# Substitution in calculus: $\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}dt$. How about the $dt=-2u^{-3}du$?

Tags: calculus

> I try to compute the following integral
>   $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}dt$$

If I set $u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}$, the integral is 
$$\int_0^{\infty} u(-2u^{-3})du$$
where $dt=-2u^{-3}du$.

But $t>0$, it is not meaningful for $dt=-2u^3du<0$. How to deal with it?

I think the answer is 
$$\int_0^{\infty} u(2u^{-3})du$$

Comment: $dt=-2u^{-3}\,du$.

Comment: the antiderivative of $\frac1{\sqrt t}$ is $2\sqrt t$; the integral doesn't converge

Comment: Also, $\int_{\infty}^0$, not $\int_0^{\infty}$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, but my question is the bound of $t>0$. So $u>0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When $t=0$ you have $u=\infty$ and when  $t=\infty$ you have $u=0$. So the inetgral becomes $\int_{\infty}^{0}$ or $-\int_0^{\infty}$ after the substitution.